# Did B'nei Yisra'el do EXACTLY as Moshe had commanded them?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, bo

There appears to be a "conflict" in what two verses are stating regarding what B'nai Yisra'el asked from the Egyptians.

The 2nd verse, which occurs just prior to their leaving Egypt says (Sefaria English translation):

[Exodus 12:35](http://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.12.35?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all):

> וּבְנֵי־יִשְׂרָאֵ֥ל עָשׂ֖וּ כִּדְבַ֣ר מֹשֶׁ֑ה וַֽיִּשְׁאֲלוּ֙
>   מִמִּצְרַ֔יִם כְּלֵי־כֶ֛סֶף וּכְלֵ֥י זָהָ֖ב **וּשְׂמָלֹֽת**׃
>
> And the children of Israel did according to the word of Moses; and
>   they asked of the Egyptians jewels of silver, and jewels of gold, and
>   **raiment**

But the 1st verse, where G-d commands Moses, it states:

[Exodus 11:2](http://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.11.2?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all):

> דַּבֶּר־נָ֖א בְּאָזְנֵ֣י הָעָ֑ם וְיִשְׁאֲל֞וּ אִ֣ישׁ ׀ מֵאֵ֣ת רֵעֵ֗הוּ
>   וְאִשָּׁה֙ מֵאֵ֣ת רְעוּתָ֔הּ כְּלֵי־כֶ֖סֶף וּכְלֵ֥י זָהָֽב׃
>
> Speak now in the ears of the people, and let them ask every man of his
>   neighbour, and every woman of her neighbour, jewels of silver, and
>   jewels of gold.’

In this verse, "raiment" is not mentioned.

Did Moses add something "behind the scenes" beyond what G-d commanded him directly? Or, did B'nai Yisra'el do something beyond Moses's commandment?

Comment: There's an answer in [Rashi](http://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Exodus.12.35?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) + [Siftei Chachamim](http://www.sefaria.org/Ikar_Siftei_Hachamim_on_Exodus.12.35.1?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all), up for grabs to anyone who has time to write it up before I do.